Decorative solar light circuit not functioning
A gift to a parent from sibling, this decorative glass solar light with LED inside does not turn off, as I believe it should, when under the sun. Something appears wrong with the simple circuit. Eventually, the rechargeable NiMH AA battery seems to runs down and shuts off. It has an on/off switch, and when flipping it, it comes back on, but for shorter intervals with the largely drained battery. When keeping it out in the sun to recharge, it doesn't seem to get a charge. I've replaced the rechargeable batteries several times, and experimented with the on/off switch.
As this is a decorative item and gift, we're not inclined to just replace it like you would a solar walkway light. Have others had a similar issue?






Does it have a photo cell to turn the unit off when the sun comes out?  If not it may just be a feature of the product to come on and be on for a predetermined period of time.  My wife has some LED candles that do that.  Once turned on they are on for 6 hours.

Yep, I've had many of these type of devices fail. Some don't even have a light shutoff circuit. (Most are rated for only a few hours of light after a full day's charge in sunlight, so the NiCd or NiMH cell is deeply cycled and fails. However, I have found a US$10 patio light with large photocell, and added a series resistor to the LED sot it's dimmer, but works all night.)

There's no photocell as one would assume, I now see. unless it were somehow hidden under the photovoltaic. Now it makes sense why it has an on/off switch. This is meant to be manually switched on, not automatically running, like landscaping solar lights, unfortunately. How annoying. Nice trick though with the resistors added, @DrMoishePippik. To futz around adding a photocell to the circuit is something I might consider. We want this on automatically. I'm not great with even basic electronics, however.

What is the absolute lux in the location it is installed, as compared to open direct sunlight?   The human eye adjusts, so we don't see it - but there can be a 1000:1 difference in absolute lux, and that makes all the difference in the world to the solar panel. @RMDman the solar panel is the photosensor.

A common cause of failure in solar lights is that the solar panel has failed, usually because of damp ingress.
With no power from the solar panel, the battery rapidly drains, and the controler IC doesn't know it's daytime so turns the LED on all the time.
It might be possible to replace the panel.  But it's probably more practical to replace the entire circuit woth one from another lamp.
